# как получить данные с PostgreSQL? js

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, get

мне нужно создать таблицу с данными из PostgreSQL, как я могу получить их? могу ли я через fetch отправить GET запрос и получить их? просто никогда не работал раньше с данной системой упрвления баз данных

Comment: запрос можно отправить на сервер, где **серверным языком прогрммирования** обратиться к БД, вытянуть данные и отправить обратно в JS.......... конечно, можно и заставить какой-нибудь сервер обратиться к БД и выплюнуть данные, но это будет как-то очень сложно....да и не делает почти никто

Comment: а как мне тогда, как фронтендеру, получить данные с PostgreSQL?

Comment: если один - изучить ЯП бэка (проще, наверное, будет nodejs ), либо найти человека, который будет писать бэк

Comment: спасибо большое, а вот когда я обращаюсь через к бэку через fetch в js, это ведь не ЯП бэка, как тогда так получается, что мне все равно данные приходят?

Comment: Не понял ничего, если честно.  https://www.internet-technologies.ru/wp-content/uploads/articles/ajax/asynchronous/1.gif